# Rounding up in Crystal report 8

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I always round up in crystal report ?
Like if the real value 3.10 it will be 4. Again if the value 3.50 or 3.90 it will be 4.

Answer (score -1):

Try following in you crystal report code:

```
-int(-({number}/.5))*.5
```